# Trouble with Form Control dropdown box

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, dropdown

I am having some trouble creating a dependent drop down box, where based on the value of the first dropdown, either a list is returned or a value is returned:

My first drop down ("Drop Down 6") is comprised of two options (a named range)

```
LU Classification:
        CFR
        DCR
```

The code for my second drop down ("Drop Down 11") is below:

```
'Declare variables
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim c_list As Worksheet

'Assign variables
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set c_list = wb.Worksheets("C_List")
      
'DropDown level 1
Dim dd As DropDown
Set dd = ws.Shapes("Drop Down 6").OLEFormat.Object

'DropDown level 2
Dim dd2 As DropDown
Set dd2 = ws.Shapes("Drop Down 11").OLEFormat.Object

'DropDown level 2 values
With dd2
    If dd.Value = 1 Then
        dd2.ListFillRange = "LU_BBP"
    Else
        dd2.ListFillRange = "Packer"
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

My if statement doesn't seem to be working, where a list should be returned, when I select CFR on the first drop down.

Any thoughts?

EDIT: If I run through line by line in the VBA editor, the drop down does update, however, when simply using the drop down the change doesn't carry over.

Comment: yes dd.Value equals either 1 or 2, based on either CFR or DCR selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this slightly differently.

Paste this code in the module

```
Option Explicit

Sub DropDown6_Change()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim dd As DropDown
    Set dd = ws.Shapes("Drop Down 6").OLEFormat.Object

    Dim dd2 As DropDown
    Set dd2 = ws.Shapes("Drop Down 11").OLEFormat.Object
    
    If dd.Value = 1 Then
        dd2.ListFillRange = "LU_BBP"
    Else
        dd2.ListFillRange = "Packer"
    End If
End Sub
```

Now right click on `Drop Down 6` and click on assign macro. Assign `DropDown6_Change` to this drop down and you are done :)

**In Action (A demo)**

[image]

Comment: Nailed it dude. Thankyou for your help, I was assigning the macro to the wrong drop down box. Appreciate your help. Cool video too. Many thanks!